# How/where to preload has_many relationship data in Phoenix 1.3

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I'm learning Elixir/Phoenix on a sample project and started with Phoenix 1.2.
Now I recreated the project with Phoenix 1.3 to see/learn differences and adapt my old code.

In there I have a `has_many` relationship between a model `Position` and `Skill`. Whereas in the 1.2 code in `position_controller.ex` I used

```ex
case Repo.insert(changeset) do
  {:ok, position} ->
    position = position |> Repo.preload(:skills)
    ...
```

to have `skills` preloaded for rendering I'm unsure where to put this in my 1.3 code.

Controller seems to be the wrong place now (`Repo` isn't even known) so I placed it into my context file inside `create_position` like this:

```ex
def create_position(attrs \\ %{}) do
  with {:ok, %Position{} = position} <-
    %Position{}
    |> Position.changeset(attrs)
    |> Repo.insert() do

    position = Repo.preload(position, :skills)
    {:ok, position}
  end
end
```

Which feels strange since it now does more than just inserting.

So what is the correct and best way to perform this task?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will want to separate things out depending on what your contexts / application looks like.

```ex
def insert_position(attrs) do
  attrs
  |> changeset()
  |> MyApp.Repo.insert()
end
```

If skills and positions are in the same context, you can do something along the lines of

```ex
def load_skills(position) do
  MyApp.Repo.preload(position, :skills)
end
```

If it is in a separate context, you can do the following

```ex
def get_skills_for_position(position) do
  # I'm not sure which way you have the relationship
  MyApp.Repo.all(from skill in MyApp.Skill, 
    join: position in MyApp.Position,
    on: skill.id == position.skill_id)
end
```

Then, in your controller, it is up to you to put these things together.

```ex
def create(conn, %{"position" => position_attrs}) do
  case create_position(position_attrs) do
    {:ok, position} ->
      # or load_skills_for_position, depending if they are in the same contexts.
      position = load_skills(position) 
      ...
    {:error, changeset} ->
      ...
  end
end
```